# Tipos de usuario C#

Tags: c#, sql

En cuanto a el primer if si me funciona para comprobar el usuario y contraseña pero el segundo me da error al entrar con el usuario de tipo 1.

> El error que me marca es: (Solo cuando entro con el usuario normal = 1)

> if (dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "2")

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'

```
            Con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from UserTbl where UsrNom='"+UnameTb.Text+"' and UsrPass='"+PassTb.Text+"'",Con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
            sda.Fill(dt);

            //Error?
            SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select UsrType from UserTbl where UsrNom='" + UnameTb.Text + "' and UsrType='" + 2 + "'", Con);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            sda2.Fill(dt2);

            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                { //Problema no me detecta los tipos de usuario
                    if (dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "2")
                    {
                        User = UnameTb.Text;
                        Admin Obj2 = new Admin();
                        Obj2.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                        Con.Close();

                    }
                    else { 
                User = UnameTb.Text;
                Panel Obj = new Panel();
                Obj.Show();
                this.Hide();
                Con.Close();}
                }
```

Comment: que esperas que tenga tu dt2?? igual, te recomendaria que dejes de usar datatables (antiquisimo) y uses EF o dapper... asi no tendrias estos problemas...

Comment: Si lo tomare en cuenta, si por lo visto no lo puse pero dt2 quiero que tenga el valor de UsrType y me da problemas en el dt2.Rows

Comment: usrType es una cadena???

Comment: usrType es de tipo int

Comment: si es int, entonces tu query esta mal.. no probaste tu consulta no? los int, no van con comillas simples, y vos lo estas mandando con comillas simples...

Comment: dt2 está vacío, por eso da un OutOfRangeException. Lo que seguramente ocurra, como te han dicho, es que tu query no devuelve ningún resultado, sea por error en la query o porque no hay registros, por lo que dt2 no se rellena con ningún resultado y se mantiene vacío, produciéndose esta excepción cuando intentas acceder a unos elementos que no tiene.